# Joining multiple tables in BigQuery gets a huge number of results

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to get the result of joining multiple tables in BigQuery, but I am getting hundreds of thousands of results instead of the 500 I originally wanted.
Is the join condition wrong?
I can get 500 results when I use merge_table, but the number of results increases when I join subsequent calculation queries.

I don't want to go into details, but here is the query

```
WITH merge_table AS (
    -- Merge tables 1 and 2 in BQ
    WITH table_1 AS (
        SELECT
            id,
            name,
            date
        FROM
            `[Table 1 in BQ]`
        UNION
        DISTINCT
        SELECT
            id,
            name,
            date
        FROM
            `[Table 2 in BQ]`
    ),
    -- Merge tables 3 and 2 in BQ
    table_2 AS (
        SELECT
            id,
            age
        FROM
            `[Table 3 in BQ]`
        UNION
        DISTINCT
        SELECT
            id,
            age
        FROM
            `[Table 2 in BQ]`
    ),
    -- Merge tables 4 and 2 in BQ
    table_3 AS (
        SELECT
            id,
            price
        FROM
            `[Table 4 in BQ]`
        UNION
        DISTINCT
        SELECT
            id,
            price
        FROM
            `[Table 2 in BQ]`
    )
    -- Get merge_table, BQ5 and BQ6 as one table
    SELECT
       [Columns to retrieve from the merged table]
    FROM
        `[Table 5 in BQ]` AS BQ5
        FULL OUTER JOIN `[Table 6 in BQ]` AS BQ6 ON BQ5.id = BQ6.id
        FULL OUTER JOIN table_1 USING(id)
        JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.id
        JOIN table_3 ON table_2.id = table_3.id
),
-- calculation1
calculation_1 AS (
    SELECT
        merge_table.id,
        [Calculation Formula]
    FROM
        merge_table
        JOIN `[Table 7 in BQ]` AS BQ7 ON merge_table.id = BQ7.id
),
-- calculation2
calculation_2 AS (
    SELECT
        BQ5.id,
        [Calculation Formula]
    FROM
        `[Table 7 in BQ]` AS BQ7
        JOIN `[Table 5 in BQ]` AS BQ5 ON BQ7.id = BQ5.id
        JOIN calculation_1 ON BQ5.id = calculation_1.id
),
-- calculation3
calculation_3 AS (
    SELECT
        merge_table.id,
        [Calculation Formula]
    FROM
        `merge_table`
        JOIN `calculation_2` ON merge_table.id = calculation_2.id
)
SELECT
    merge_table.*,
    calculation_1.[Calculation results],
    calculation_2.[Calculation results1],
    calculation_2.[Calculation results2],
    calculation_3.[Calculation results1],
    calculation_3.[Calculation results2]
FROM
    merge_table
    JOIN calculation_1 ON calculation_1.id = merge_table.id 
    JOIN calculation_2 ON calculation_1.id = calculation_2.id 
    JOIN calculation_3 ON calculation_2.id = calculation_3.id
```

Comment: The `JOIN` condition is wrong if you are are getting way more rows than you expect.  So the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: @GordonLinoff    Thank you. Could you please tell me what exactly is wrong?